# Linux user auto login and disable keyboard

Tags: embedded-linux, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to build a digital sign using a Jetson device running Ubuntu connected to a HDMI monitor. The device does not have a GUI or X server running. It displays the required image directly to the framebuffer from within a non-interactive Docker container (by binding '-v /dev/fb0:/dev/fb0' when running the container).

The boot sequence is as follows: User 'restricted_user' gets logged in automatically (I edited the getty@tty1 service to include '-a restricted_user'), and then the container is started as a separate systemd service.

Now I would like to disable the keyboard for this user, so that someone can't come along and plug a keyboard into the device and start making changes. The only way to stop the container service should be via ssh. I would also like to hide the terminal from the screen, so that only the image being written to the framebuffer gets displayed (i.e. no command prompt, flashing cursor, etc.)

I tried removing the 'restricted_user' from group 'input'. I also looked at the permissions for the event0 to event9 devices, but these didn't include any permissions for non-group users.